# Is it possible to use more_like_this across different data types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

[The documentation for `more_like_this`](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#more-like-this) shows how you can use it to get more of the same type of content that is similar based on a criteria:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do
    # The :more_like_this option must be set to true
    text :body, :more_like_this => true
  end
end

post = Post.first

results = Sunspot.more_like_this(post) do
  fields :body
  minimum_term_frequency 5
end
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to return related items that are a different data type. For example, `Videos` that are related/similar to `Articles`.

I guess this depends on whether `more_like_this` is operating along the lines of "more `Articles` that are similar to this `Article` based on a set of criteria" or if it's operating along the lines of "more things that are similar to this `Article` based on a set of criteria"...

My use-case for this would be if I'm displaying an `Article`, and I want to show related content on the side of the page - things that might be other `Articles`, `Videos` in the same category, or `Events` on related topics, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://sunspot.github.com/sunspot/docs/Sunspot.html#more_like_this-class_method

> + (Object) more_like_this(object, *types, &block) Initiate a MoreLikeThis search. MoreLikeThis is a special type of search that
>   finds similar documents using fulltext comparison. The fields to be
>   compared are `text` fields set up with the `:more_like_this` option
>   set to `true`. By default, more like this returns objects of the same
>   type as the object used for comparison, but a list of types can
>   optionally be passed to this method to return similar documents of
>   other types. This will only work for types that have common fields.

example:

```
  post = Post.first
  Sunspot.more_like_this(post, Post, Page) do
    fields :title, :body
    with(:updated_at).greater_than(1.month.ago)
    facet(:category_ids)
  end
```

see also: http://sunspot.github.com/sunspot/docs/Sunspot/Query/MoreLikeThis.html

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I'm running up against [this bug](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/148) which prohibits passing multiple objects through `more_like_this` - so, `Page` in your example ... or `Sunspot.more_like_this(post, Post, Page, Video, Event)` as another example fails with an `undefined method 'more_like_this_fields'` error.